# What is the best way to monitor (java) process deaths on a Windows box?

Tags: java, windows, process, trace

We have a curious problem with our java processes dying.

The application doesn't stacktrace, or write anything to the logs, the process just randomly dies. It's a heavily used application, but the problem only appears about once a month.

We're currently looking into using [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) but any other suggestions would be welcome.

**Edit:**

It's a distributed Java application, running on Weblogic with an in-house web framework (Yes, this is a terrible idea, but it's been running for eight years), connecting to Oracle.

-

*Out of Memory?*
Our logs would catch java.lang.OutOfMemoryException, according to Brian Agnew.

*Write crashes to a log?* I don't think Java ever gets the chance, the death is happening at a process level, rather than Java exiting.

Comment: Don't depend on OutOfMemoryException will appear in any log. There might be even not enough memory free to throw the OOME and the java process will "silently" die.

Answer (score 2):

Can you wrap it in some shell script that captures the log files (stdout/stderr) and the exit code (which should give some indication as to how it died) ? On JVM exit you can also capture machine level stats using [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582.aspx)

IF the VM itself is crashing it'll leave behind an hs_err_pid... file that contains stacktraces, machine-level debug info. You can then use that to diagnose the VM issue. See [this blog entry](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2009/02/crash_course_on.html) for further information.

If the problem is related to the app's behaviour, it may be worth looking at [JConsole](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jconsole.html), although from your description of the issue, this sounds much more like a low level VM issue.

(I assume you're on the latest VM for your Java version number etc.)

Comment: I've scanned the entire drive, and no files contain 'hs_err' in the file-name. I imagine this means that the VM isn't crashing.

I'll look into WMI and JConsole, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Linux NAGIOS Server to monitor the health of your Windows machines and services! Have a look at: [nagios-monitoring-windows](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/monitoring-windows.html).

If you have such problems with your java app! You should test it and debug it! Applications shouldn't die without a trace! Look for logfiles! From which vendor is the app? Or is it self written? Try to enforce another Log4J/Logger/Debug Level. Monitor your System with cacti etc. to reduce the possibilities for such a crash. Talk to the software vendor.

Is enogh memory available? Maybe the app runs out of memory? Is it a standalone java process or a java process from a tomcat/jboss server?

Have you written down the crash times to a log? Appear they in different time-slices? Or appear they nearly time-circular?

Comment: The VM won't crash if it runs out of memory. It'll fail to allocate more from the OS, and throw java.lang.OutOfMemoryExceptions, but the VM will stay up

Answer (score 0):

VisualVM is a new tool which makes monitoring Java applications easier:

https://visualvm.dev.java.net/description.html

"VisualVM is a tool that provides detailed information about Java applications while they are running. It provides an intuitive graphical user interface that allows you to easily see information about multiple Java applications."